# Storing inputs from multiple SELECT tags into a PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-select

I have an input field iterated 3 times and I would like to store the values entered in each of the fields in a PHP array.

I called each OPTION **`item[]`** hoping that it would save each value in a same array.

Would this work? If yes, how would I retrieve it on PHP?

Here is my form:

```
<tr>
    <td>Items</td>
    <td><select><?php
    $items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr");
    $items ->execute();
    while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <option name="item[]" value="<?=$info['id_item']?>"><?=$info['name']?></option><?php } ?>
    </td>
    <td>Quantity:</td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]"></td>
        <td><a href="" id="addItem">ADD</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="moreItems">
    <td>Items</td>
    <td><select><?php
    while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <option name="item[]" value="<?=$info['id_item']?>"><?=$info['name']?></option><?php } ?>
    </td>
    <td>Quantity:</td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moreItems">
    <td>Items</td>
    <td><select><?php
    while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <option name="item[]" value="<?=$info['id_item']?>"><?=$info['name']?></option><?php } ?>
    </td>
    <td>Quantity:</td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You need to set the `name` attribute on the `select` tag, not the `option` tag

Comment: Thx, that would work for the SELECT. How about for the INPUT field?

Comment: works the same.. name="something[]" after post to php would be `$_POST['something'][0]` = 'sample', `$_POST['something'][1]` = 'sample'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `[]` from the option tag to your select tag:

```
<tr>
    <td>Items</td>
    <td><select name="items[]">
    <?php
        $items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr");
        $items ->execute();

        while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <option name="item" value="<?=$info['id_item']?>"><?=$info['name']?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </td>
    <td>Quantity:</td>
    <td><input name="quantity[]"></td>
    <td><a href="" id="addItem">ADD</a></td>
</tr>
```

Then on your PHP page, to retrieve the values:

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $key => $itemValue)
{
    echo 'Item: ' . $itemValue . '<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: ' . $_POST['quantity'][$key] . '<br /><br />';
}
```